# Gradient XML drawable center not working

Tags: android, xml, gradient, android-drawable, android-resources

I am trying to create an XML gradient drawable to match this style mentioned in [Material Design guidelines](https://material.google.com/style/imagery.html#imagery-ui-integration)

[image: Gradient guideline]

This is my XML code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerY="30%"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="#4d000000"
        android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

I already tried to set the centerY to 0.3 too, without success. The drawable always look the same in preview.

Can someone tell me what to do to achieve that style? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't quite see your mistake. It could be possible that you first have to set the centerColor. Take a look at the docs if you haven't already:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

But before hustling with a XML drawable that will give you a linear gradient, I suggest you to use Roman Nuriks attempt to this problem. See more here: 
https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/2QvHVFWrHZf
He solved the problem by using a Java implementation of a Drawable. Works as any other drawable.

Comment: I had to set centerColor indeed. Roman Nurik's code is great, but I don't really need it and find it too complicated for something so simple. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 16):

centerX/centerY don't work without setting centerColor.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#FFCCCCCC"
    android:centerColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:centerY="0.9"
    android:type="linear"
    />
```

You must set `android:centerColor`, This way work for me fine.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything that the other answers do not already explain. Please feel free to suggest an edit to the other answers if you think they can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:centerColor="#b6babd"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="#62471a"
    android:centerY="30%"
    />
```

I set `centerColor` with another color just for you to see how works but you can change to transparent.

The `centerY` attribute works with `centerColor`.